# Send email using SMTPClient.jl in Julia: curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: smtp, julia, smtpclient

I tried to run exactly the same code in the following link (with real email addresses and password, of course) in Julia to send email:

https://github.com/aviks/SMTPClient.jl

However I received the error message: 
`curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK`

The same code runs smoothly in my Linux machine (Ubuntu with Julia 1.3.0) and returns the error message only in Windows (Windows 10 with Julia 1.2.0, but doesn't work even after I updated it to Julia 1.3.1). How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing CURL and its SSL for windows: (https://bintray.com/vszakats/generic/curl/7.67.0 or https://curl.haxx.se/).

Perhaps Julia's copy of LibCURL under Windows is looking for an SSH library that is misconfigured.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work ... It seems that CURL had already been installed and it still returns an error even after I installed SSL (OpenSSL-Win64)

Comment: You might need to make sure that the downloaded curl dll and openssl dll are on your path and then rebuild LibCURL, or even update Julia itself.